# How do I use value of variable in Maple

Tags: maple

How do I get Maple to give the value of a variable in the RHS of an expression, rather than treat it as a variable in an expression.  In the following code I want a list of three functions of x which are quadratics with different offsets, but it's not what I get:

```
ix := [-1,0,1]:
b := []:
for a in ix
do
  b := [op(b),x->(x-a)^2];
end do;
```

and the output is

[image: Maple output]

while I would like it to be (for the last line)

```
b := [ x -> (x+1)^2, x -> x^2, x -> (x-1)^2 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to use values for `a` in the construction of the *body of a procedure*, and not the "*RHS of an expression*" as you stated.

Try not to use the term "function" in this context, as it just muddles the distinction between expression and procedure.

Here is a way to get the values from `ix` as replacements for `a` in a generated list of *procedures* with `(x-a)^2` in the body.

```
restart;
ix := [-1,0,1]:

b := []:
for a in ix do
  b := [op(b), unapply((x-a)^2,x)];
end do:
b;

    [x -> (x+1)^2, x -> x^2, x -> (x-1)^2]
```

It is inefficient to construct lists in this way, by repeatedly concatenating them. Since that practice scales badly in performance you really ought to drop it as a practice.

You can construct the whole list with one call to `seq`.

```
Flist := [ seq( unapply((x-a)^2,x), a in ix ) ]:

Flist;

    [x -> (x+1)^2, x -> x^2, x -> (x-1)^2]
```

Here, `Flist` is a list of procedures, each of which can be evaluated at a value by calling it with an argument.

```
Flist[1];

              x -> (x+1)^2

Flist[3](3.4);

                  5.76

#plot(Flist, -2..2);
```

Note: Procedures which display with the arrow notation `x -> ...` are called *operators*.

For fun, here are equivalents, using *expressions*,

```
Elist := [ seq( (x-a)^2, a in ix ) ]:

Elist;

        [       2   2         2]
        [(x + 1) , x , (x - 1) ]

Elist[1];

                       2
                (x + 1) 

eval(Elist[3], x=3.4);

                  5.76

#plot(Elist, x=-2..2);
```

There are other ways to generate the procedures, with values of `a` in the body being specified programmatically. The `unapply` command is not the only possible mechanism, although it is the easiest for your example.

Another way is to substitute, for example,

```
generic := x -> (x-_dummy)^2:

Hlist := [ seq( subs(_dummy=a, eval(generic)), a in ix ) ]:

Hlist;

    [x -> (x+1)^2, x -> x^2, x -> (x-1)^2]
```

Comment: Thanks the answer, and all the extras (including lessons in nomenclature).  It's what I was after, and then some 